# define custom permissions in J3.5.x

Tags: custom-component, acl

I work on an extension that defines a number of custom permissions. We've done this through  elements in the access.xml file, and up until J3.5.x it was working fine.

Now we're finding that the permissions will display in the ACL permissions config, but when we change the options and save -- none of the settings are actually saved.

Are there changes in 3.5.x with how those permissions need to be defined?

Comment: I think I found the issue. Our permission actions were defined frequently using underscores, e.g. "mycomponent.custom_perm". The Joomla ACL permissions form splits on the underscore when storing in the assets table rules column. Basically -- it completely breaks how the permission is stored, simply because an underscore is used. Does anyone know why that change was made? Was it intentional? It's a huge backward compatibility issue for us. Not only does it mean a lot of code updates to alter the permission names, but there is potentially a lot of DB cleanup required.

Answer (score 2):

The underscores in permission names is indeed the problem. Fortunately, others have run into this issue and there is a patch already submitted that should be included in 3.5.2. Details here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/9648

Comment: They are skipping 3.5.2, but chances are it will be in 3.6 https://volunteers.joomla.org/reports/238-production-leadership-team-minutes-1st-may-2016